# SSH-deployer fails with auth fail error message - Teamcity for scp?

Tags: teamcity

I have a build in Teamcity with the SSH-deployer, but it fails with Auth fail. I am using password authentication, don't wanna use private/public key authentication as it won't be robust approach for us.

Idea is to authenticate via user name and password.

Attached the screenshot for the configuration.

Thanks

[image: Config]

Error message:

```
    [06:16:14]Collecting changes in 1 VCS root
[06:16:14][Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] VCS Root details
[06:16:14][VCS Root details] "DE_Automation" {instance id=40631, parent internal id=7496, parent id=Abc_DeAutomation, description: "ssh://git@<server_name>/abc/puppet.git#refs/heads/master"}
[06:16:15]Clearing temporary directory: /opt/teamcity/temp/buildTmp
[06:16:15]Publishing internal artifacts
[06:16:15][Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]
[06:16:15][Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]
[06:16:15]Checkout directory: /opt/teamcity/work/376a4e836d9c66e4
[06:16:15]Updating sources: server side checkout
[06:16:15][Updating sources] Using vcs information from agent file: 376a4e836d9c66e4.xml
[06:16:16][Updating sources] Building incremental patch for VCS root: DE_Automation; checkout rules: =>; revision: d88b7e07953108a1a4c392887c28e9b97ce31a5b --> d88b7e07953108a1a4c392887c28e9b97ce31a5b
[06:16:16][Updating sources] Repository sources transferred
[06:16:16]Step 1/3: Command Line
[06:16:16][Step 1/3] Disabled build step Command Line is skipped
[06:16:16]Step 2/3: SFTP (FTP Deployer)
[06:16:16][Step 2/3] Disabled build step SFTP (FTP Deployer) is skipped
[06:16:16]Step 3/3: SCP (SSH Deployer)
[06:16:16][Step 3/3] com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
[06:16:16]
[Step 3/3] com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:512)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.deployer.agent.ssh.SSHSessionProvider.<init>(SSHSessionProvider.java:102)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.deployer.agent.ssh.SSHDeployerRunner.getDeployerProcess(SSHDeployerRunner.java:44)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.deployer.agent.base.BaseDeployerRunner.createBuildProcess(BaseDeployerRunner.java:47)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.runner.CallRunnerService.doCreateBuildProcess(CallRunnerService.java:71)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.runner.CallRunnerService.createBuildProcess(CallRunnerService.java:47)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.runnerStages.start.CallRunnerStage.doBuildStage(CallRunnerStage.java:47)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.RunnerStagesExecutor$1.callStage(RunnerStagesExecutor.java:25)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.RunnerStagesExecutor$1.callStage(RunnerStagesExecutor.java:18)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.callRunStage(StagesExecutor.java:78)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.doStages(StagesExecutor.java:37)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.RunnerStagesExecutor.doStages(RunnerStagesExecutor.java:18)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.RunnerContextExecutor.callRunnerStages(RunnerContextExecutor.java:43)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.StepExecutor.processNextStep(StepExecutor.java:25)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.ForEachBuildRunnerStage.executeRunnerStep(ForEachBuildRunnerStage.java:138)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.ForEachBuildRunnerStage.runStep(ForEachBuildRunnerStage.java:123)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.ForEachBuildRunnerStage.executeBuildRunners(ForEachBuildRunnerStage.java:83)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.ForEachBuildRunnerStage.doBuildStage(ForEachBuildRunnerStage.java:44)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor$1.callStage(BuildStagesExecutor.java:31)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor$1.callStage(BuildStagesExecutor.java:24)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.callRunStage(StagesExecutor.java:78)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.doStages(StagesExecutor.java:37)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor.doStages(BuildStagesExecutor.java:24)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildRunActionImpl.doStages(BuildRunActionImpl.java:70)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildRunActionImpl.runBuild(BuildRunActionImpl.java:50)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl.doActualBuild(BuildAgentImpl.java:288)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl.access$100(BuildAgentImpl.java:53)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl$1.run(BuildAgentImpl.java:252)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[06:16:16][Step 3/3] Step SCP (SSH Deployer) failed with unexpected error
[06:16:16]Publishing internal artifacts
[06:16:16][Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [WebPublisher]
[06:16:16][Publishing internal artifacts] Publishing 1 file using [ArtifactsCachePublisher]
[06:16:16]Build finished
```

Comment: your server name is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was not related to SCP (even when TC was saying it is) at all:

My steps:

1. compile
2. SCP deploy
3. some cleanup
4. shh script on remote server

And step 2 was failing with the same error message as you (but when i SSH to remote server, the file was here)

But, the problem was not in failing step #2 but two steps ahead - i had wrong user in step #4!

Looks like some sort of async bug.